# Align image left in jQuery Mobile collapsible div

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v9PhM/) of the problem here. When I have an image with `align="left"` inside a collapsible div, it doesn't size correctly, and overflows the div.

Is there a different way I should be doing this? If not, how can I workaround this? Is it a bug?

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

After the image

http://jsfiddle.net/soparrissays/v9PhM/1/

Answer (score 0):

Align left is equal to float left, so I would say - no, thats not a bug.

http://jsfiddle.net/v9PhM/2/

I would just put display block on the image.